# How to fix function with for loop not iterating. Recommendation system in Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, machine-learning, data-science, recommendation-engine

I'm working on a recommendation system with the python library Surprise.
I'm trying to make a function that iterates over the full list of movies and predicts their ranking value against a user id which is defined in when I call the function.

This is for Python3 with the library surprise and the SVD algorithm. The dataset is from open source MovieLens: [Link to the dataset](https://grouplens.org/datasets/movielens/100k/)

```py
from surprise import Dataset
from surprise import Reader
from surprise import SVD
import pandas as pd

reader = Reader(line_format='user item rating timestamp', sep='\t')
data = Dataset.load_from_file('./dataset/ml-100k/u.data', reader=reader)
movies = pd.read_csv('./dataset/ml-100k/u.item',sep='|', encoding='latin-1', usecols=[0,1], names=['iid', 'name'])
algorithm = SVD()
trainset = data.build_full_trainset()
algorithm.fit(trainset)

def prediction(uid):
    ratings=[]
    for iid in movies['iid']:
        pred = algorithm.predict(uid, iid)
        ratings.append(pred[3])
    return ratings

prediction(321)
```

I expect the function to build a list of ratings (value [3] of prediction) for each item and a single user given in the function calling.

```
[3.52986,
 3.69845,
 2.98954,
 3.00545,
 3.84254,
 ...]
```

But the actual output is a list with length equal to the length of the list of movies (which is fine) but with the same rating repeated over and over.

```
 [3.52986,
 3.52986,
 3.52986,
 3.52986,
 3.52986,
 3.52986,
 3.52986,
 3.52986,
 ...]
```

So seing the actual output I think there is a problem with the for loop which iterates and appends the result but uses the same iid on each iteration. I'm trying to make a function where the uid stays fixed but the iid changes for each iteration.

EDIT: as suggested I added print(iid) inside the loop and it iterates correctly printing all the iids. But it doesn't work inside the pred = algorithm.predict(uid, iid) line

Comment: This question is lacking a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I don't know how to do that without having to copy a lot of code. I'll try.

Comment: there, I think now we havea minimal reproducible example. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks. I've edited the code. Sadly I've got the same output.  Also I want the ratings list to be filled by ratings for the whole movies dataset given the user id.

Comment: if you `print(iid)` inside the for loop does it iterate?

Comment: it prints the iids correctly, still doesn't work inside pred = algorithm.predict(uid, iid)

Comment: I've done more testing. The loop works fine, it's the pred = algorithm.predict(uid, iid) the one that returns the same rating for all combinations between uid and iid... Should I close the question? or just change the subject?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The loop was ok. It seems that I was using the incorrect method to return results of the SVD algorithm.
Meanwhile I've found the following code which produces somewhat similar results to what I was looking for with my own function.

Thanks everyone for your time and effort.

```py
   from collections import defaultdict
   testset = trainset.build_anti_testset()
   predictions = algorithm.test(testset)

   def get_top_n(predictions, n=10):
   top_n = defaultdict(list)
   for uid, iid, true_r, est, _ in predictions:
       top_n[uid].append((iid, est))
   for uid, user_ratings in top_n.items():
       user_ratings.sort(key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
       top_n[uid] = user_ratings[:n]
   return top_n

   top_n = get_top_n(predictions, n=10)

   for uid, user_ratings in top_n.items():
   print(uid, [iid for (iid, _) in user_ratings])
```

```
196 ['408', '127', '190', '187', '318', '64', '191', '357', '169', '272']
186 ['496', '165', '515', '923', '318', '313', '64', '223', '530', '478']
22 ['22', '205', '357', '100', '169', '923', '64', '269', '69', '285']
244 ['474', '127', '408', '483', '285', '12', '1142', '134', '493', '480']
166 ['318', '174', '408', '98', '483', '64', '480', '114', '169', '511']
298 ['64', '169', '12', '478', '114', '272', '166', '408', '513', '923']
115 ['408', '168', '114', '285', '483', '919', '169', '480', '179', '189']
```